# How to show sub list on click of vertical sidebar menu using css and html?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a sidebar in which there are href's and on click of particular href , I want to show the list of data.

I have used css with html to get the desired results , but when i click on href , i want to append the buttons to that href only but it is appending the buttons to the bottom of side bar.

```
<script 
src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"> 
</script>
<div class="sidenav">
<a href="#" onclick="javascript:myFunc()">col1</a>
<a href="#">col2</a>
<script> function myFunc() {

var $container = $("#container");
var $sidebar = $("#sidebar");
var button = $('<button />');
var item= 'abc';
button.text(item);
$sidebar.append(button);
var data='cde';
var button = $('<button />');
button.text(data);
$sidebar.append(button);
}</script>

</div>
<div id="container">
    <div id="sidebar">
    </div>
</div>
```

here is the link to what i have tried-https://jsfiddle.net/gaurav10022/exrLaz14/1/
I want that buttons gets appended after col1 not col2 and also when i click on col1 again it toggles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure you are looking exactly what, however, **You can try with below approach.** just hide the div during page load and show and hide based on click event.

```js
function myFunc() {
  var $container = $("#container");
  var $sidebar = $("#sidebar");
  if($sidebar.children().length <= 0) {
    var button = $('<button />');
    var item= 'abc';
    button.text(item);
    $sidebar.append(button);

    var data='cde';
    var button = $('<button />');
    button.text(data);
    $sidebar.append(button);

    $('#col1').append($container);
  } else {
    $sidebar.html('');
  }
  
}
```

```css
.sidenav {
  width: 100px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 101;
  left: 201;
  background: #FFF;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  padding: 8px 0;
}
.sidenav a {
  padding: 6px 8px 6px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #818181;
  display: block;
}
.sidenav a:hover {
  color: #064579;
}
button {
   display: block;
   cursor: pointer; 
   background-color: #FFF;
 }
```

```html
<script 
src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"> 
</script>

<div class="sidenav">
<a href="#" onclick="myFunc()" id= "col1">col1</a>
<a href="#">col2</a>
</div>

<div id="container" style="dsiplay: none">
    <div id="sidebar">
    </div>
</div>
```

**Please don't hesitate to let me know if you have any further query.**

Comment: I am creating buttons dynamically and appending to sidebar according to the data , i am getting from a server. I have to toggle sidebar content. can you please help me

Comment: Would you please check it now?

Comment: thanks a ton and also could you tell me what is the way to handle the content on menu as when i click on col1 , it shows two buttons and when i click on the button, it shows table content, i want that when i click col2 , col1 content gets cleared after saving and col2 content gets displayed

Comment: you are most welcome... you have to clear the content of sidebar using sidebar.html('') when you click col2. that's it.. best of luck.

Comment: but sidebar.html('') will not work when clicked on col2, because i have another function to display content for col2, sidebar is defined for col1 myfunct only?

Comment: I have to clear the content of col1, when clicked on col2 and display the content of col2